# IOS Keypad is getting displayed slowly for Password UITextField

Tags: passwords, uitextfield, ios14, xcode12

I am new to iOS application development and i came across an issue where keypad is getting displayed after a delay of almost 6 to 8 seconds  for Password UITextField. For other text fields like username, email etc the keypad is getting displayed immediately.

When I disable the Secure Text Type property for password text field in the storyboard then the keypad is getting displayed immediately for the password text field also. But password text the user has ttped is visible as I have disabled the Secure Text Type.  I am running the app in IPad having iOS version 14.2.

Can you please suggest on how to display the keypad immediately for password text fields ?